# How to set NDK_MODULE_PATH in Android Studio and/or gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm in the process of migrating an Android Library from Eclipse to Android Studio. In Eclipse I could set NDK_MODULE_PATH via Project > Properties > Resource > Linked Resources > Path Variables. But how do I achieve the same thing in Android Studio respectively with gradle?

My library builds until it tries to find the headers for a module under NDK_MODULE_PATH.

Here's the error message:

```
Executing tasks: [:libAndroid:compileDebugSources, :physicaloidLibrary:compileDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:libAndroid:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:checkDebugManifest
:libAndroid:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:compileLint
:physicaloidLibrary:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
:physicaloidLibrary:prepareReleaseDependencies
:physicaloidLibrary:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:physicaloidLibrary:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:prepareLibAndroidGradlePhysicaloidLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:prepareDebugDependencies
:libAndroid:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:libAndroid:compileDebugNdk
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"/home/rhodo/dev/android/studio/LibAndroidGradle/libAndroid/src/main/jni/imageprocessing/dmtxutil.c:30:18: fatal error: dmtx.h: No such file or directory","position":{},"original":"/home/rhodo/dev/android/studio/LibAndroidGradle/libAndroid/src/main/jni/imageprocessing/dmtxutil.c:30:18: fatal error: dmtx.h: No such file or directory"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":" #include \u003cdmtx.h\u003e","position":{},"original":" #include \u003cdmtx.h\u003e"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"                  ^","position":{},"original":"                  ^"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compilation terminated.","position":{},"original":"compilation terminated."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"make: *** [/home/rhodo/dev/android/studio/LibAndroidGradle/libAndroid/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/Rhodo//home/rhodo/dev/android/studio/LibAndroidGradle/libAndroid/src/main/jni/imageprocessing/dmtxutil.o] Error 1","position":{},"original":"make: *** [/home/rhodo/dev/android/studio/LibAndroidGradle/libAndroid/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/Rhodo//home/rhodo/dev/android/studio/LibAndroidGradle/libAndroid/src/main/jni/imageprocessing/dmtxutil.o] Error 1"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':libAndroid:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/android-ndk/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.763 secs
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At the root of the Android Studio project, there is a file called "local.properties".  Add a property named "ndk.dir" and set the value to point to the location of the ndk.  Something like the following:

```
ndk.dir=/Users/username/sdk
```

I may not be understanding your question.  If you've already set the location of the ndk and just want to make sure a module gets built then add the module to the "settings.gradle" file.

```
include ":<your module name>"
```

Then make sure you put the C code in "src/main/jni" in the module.  Gradle will find it automatically based on the folder name.  There is no longer a need to set the NDK_MODULE_PATH.

Comment: I think you got me right, but just to clarify: There are different uses of the term "module", a module under $NDK_MODULE_PATH is a C/C++ module/library.

I created a gradle module in my library project. But then "Android.mk" makefiles are ignored. There are several posts out in the internet relating to this topic. But if one relies on these makefiles, a build of the C/C++ library may not succeed.

E.g. "libdmtx": I only needed to add "dmtx.c" to the makefile and it successfully builds. Without makefiles ndk-build tries to build every file that folder and the build fails.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

- Gradle version: 3.3
- Android plugin version: com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1

This works for me:

```
android {

    ...

    defaultConfig {

        ...

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }

        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                // TODO replace jniDependencies folder with the path to your modules
                arguments "NDK_MODULE_PATH:=${rootProject.projectDir}/jniDependencies"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }


}
```

This way I don't need to add NDK_MODULE_PATH to my PATH in order to build the project. However, the clean task fails, because that won't pick up the argument from here, so I needed to add another hack to fix that:

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeCleanTask) {
    it.actions.clear()

    doLast {
        project.delete("${projectDir}/.externalNativeBuild")
    }
}
```